# UTC clock based on server time?

Tags: php, javascript, date, time

I have a JavaScript clock that gets the time in UTC, it currently works, but the time is based off the client's computer. What could I do to base the time off of the server instead? I am using PHP as the server scripting language. I would like to not use AJAX.

```
<?php
$year   = date("Y");
$month  = date("m");
$day    = date("d");
$hour   = date("h");
$minute = date("i");
$str    = $year . $month . $day . $hour . $minute;
echo "history.pushState('', 'title', '?q=$str');";
echo "var ct = '$str';";
?>
function dT(){
    var d = new Date();
    d = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds());
    d.setTime(d.getTime());
    v = d.getFullYear() + "" +
            padstr(d.getMonth()) + "" +
            padstr(d.getDate()) + "" +
            padstr(d.getHours()) + "" +
            padstr(d.getMinutes()) + "" + padstr(d.getSeconds());
    if(ct !== v){
        history.pushState('', 'title', '?q=' + v);
        ct = v;
    }
    setTimeout('dT()', 1000);
}
dT();
```

**Edit**

```
    var a = moment().format("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>");
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = a;
    function clock_tick(){
        var time = moment(a);
        time.add('second', 1);
        a = time.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = a;
        setTimeout("clock_tick()", 1000);
    }
    clock_tick();
```

Comment: Did you search the site? Common question.

Comment: yes, I can't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. You don't need to use moment.js, but I wanted to try it out since someone suggested it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#clock')[0].innerHTML = moment().format("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>");
    clock_tick();
});
function clock_tick(){
    var clock_div = $('#clock')[0];
    var time = moment(clock_div.innerHTML);
    time.add('second', 1);
    clock_div.innerHTML = time.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    setTimeout("clock_tick()", 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then as I stated earlier you may need to set:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

Reference Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I know how to set it using php, I just need a background clock on the client side that is in UTC according to my server not their local time.

Comment: Okay, I will alter the code a bit, you would just need to pass that variable to the clientside code on page load, and then you can also use some ajax to call back to the server every once in awhile if you want to resync it.

Comment: I am having some issues, I don't know what is wrong (see question edit). The innerHTML outside the function I get `2013-05-03 03:24:13` which is correct, but once I add the interval I get `2013-05-03 03:05:00` all the time.

Comment: Either use JQuery's Document Ready Like I do, or add onload='$('#clock')[0].innerHTML = moment().format("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>");
    clock_tick();"' to the body.

Comment: that doesn't matter, the javascript works, It is just that it is formatting it wrong after it adds one second.

Comment: Oh I see, use a lowercase m for minutes, you have uppercase which stands for month.

Answer (score 0):

```
moment(give ur value).format('L');
```

that will returns the local time. see the below url it got lots of formatting options, will fit your needs.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: That isn't based off of the server's time.